Github actions Configure AWS credentials Error: The security token included in the request is invalid
I am trying to setup a Github Actions workflow that automatically builds a docker image from my repo and pushes it to Amazon ECR.
Here is my code for aws.yml, which is based on this tutorial by github here.
name: Deploy to Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  AWS_REGION: ap-southeast-2                   # set this to your preferred AWS region, e.g. us-west-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY: z-coord-repo/api-service           # set this to your Amazon ECR repository name
  ECS_SERVICE: z-coord                 # set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER: z-coord-cluster                 # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: .aws/task-definition.json  # set this to the path to your Amazon ECS task definition
                                               # file, e.g. .aws/task-definition.json

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      working-directory: ./api-service
      run: |
        # Build a docker container and
        # push it to ECR so that it can
        # be deployed to ECS.
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

However, this workflow keeps failing, giving the error The security token included in the request is invalid.. After some googling, I learned that a workaround is to include the IAM session token as a secret, and add it to the "Configure AWS Credentials" action. The new action is like so:
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
        aws-session-token: ${{ secrets.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}

This modified workflow runs and works as expected, however the session token expires after some time. Sure enough, when I tried it again the next day I got an error saying that the token had expired. In order to get it to run again, I would need to manually copy-paste the new session token into the github secret every day.
Is this expected behaviour? If so, why does the tutorial not mention this? I feel like I'm missing something.
EDIT 1:
So I might have simply made a noob mistake. I assumed I had to use the IAM credentials from the AWS access portal:

And I've noticed that all 3 get changed automatically after some time anyway. I think this means we're not supposed to use these credentials here. I think the actual credentials required are the ones described here. I will ask my administrator for this and update this post in time.
EDIT 2
Both my admin and I are new to AWS. We tried for a while to follow the instructions here, but I was not able to choose the "Security credentials" button as described in step 2 as it never appeared for me, no matter how many permissions the admin gave me.
I am thinking this is because my account was created in the IAM Identity Center instead of IAM. I'm not sure but it seems these are two different types of users?
Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. We will experiment with creating an IAM user instead. I will update this post in time.

I have an almost identical GitHub workflow and I just compared it to what you have. The differences are: 1. Remove the aws-session-token from the configure-aws-credentials step. 2. Change the amazon-ecr-login step to v2. Try that to see if it helps.

Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. The workflow never reaches the "amazon-ecr-login" step, it already fails at the "configure-aws-credentials" step.
However I've just had a thought, perhaps the IAM credentials I have are wrong? I'm using the credentials for a power user. If I may ask, what type of user are you using?

Hi, I have realised a mistake I made on my end and have updated my post accordingly.

My issue was that I had misunderstood what access keys I was supposed to use. Initially, I thought that I had to use the access keys from the AWS Access Portal (see screenshot in EDIT1), but those keys are temporary and are supposed to be used for logging in to AWS from the terminal.
Instead, I am supposed to create an IAM user within my own account using the IAM dashboard (not the IAM Identity Center), and grant it the relevant permissions for pushing to the ECR and creating and deploying task definitions. In case this helps anyone, here are the permission policies I created:
// AllowPushToAllRepo 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

// CreateTaskDefinition
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:DescribeServices",
                "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:UpdateService"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


(I am aware that setting the resource to "*" is a bad practice. I will change this once I figure out how to correctly set the ARN so that it points to the multiple different resources I want.)
This IAM user will be able to see the resources created by me in my account. I used this user's access keys to authorize the workflow.
As pointed out to me in another answer by Arnold Daniels, Amazon does not recommend this practice. Instead, I should be using the OIDC method. From what I understand, the OIDC method only allows a certain GitHub repository to perform actions on AWS, and this is why it is more safe. I will be looking into switching to that method in the future.

AWS highly recommends not using access tokens for CI workflows, but use AWS OpenID Connect (OIDC) instead. This is less prone to errors and much more secure, since the role is locked to a specific GitHub organization or repository.
1. Add GitHub as Identity Provider


For the provider URL: Use https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
For the "Audience": Use sts.amazonaws.com

2. Create an IAM role
Create an IAM web identity role with the proper privileges to push to AWS ECR.

3. Configure GitHub actions to assume the role
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{ env.AWS_ACCOUNT }}:role/${{ env.AWS_ROLE }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}


For more information see "Use IAM roles to connect GitHub Actions to actions in AWS
".

Thanks for your suggestion. It seems there are many things I still do not understand about AWS. During experimentation, we found that in creating a new IAM user (user, not role), we could get it's access keys but it could not push to the existing repo, as it seems all repos are separated by user? So I want to ask if we create this ROLE, will it be able to push to the same repository as my current IAM user account?

@A-Abe The repos are not reserated by users. If you give the role the same permissions as the user, it will be able to push the image to ECR.
